# Image manipulations with category images

Tags: image, categories

Is it possible to use image manipulations with category images? I have heard conflicting reports and it's not working for me. There is a spot to designate image manipulations for category images, but it does not work to reference `{category_image:medium}` in a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this on 2.5.5 and it doesn't work. I noticed a few posts in the forums that EL staff said this might not even be available. There was one forum post which I wasn't able to read because it was for "development preview" members so, I wonder if that is the fix being tested or something.

I can agree with Michael in that it does in fact create the folder and resize the image though, the tag isn't being parsed. You just get the tag itself like Mike said.

Consider submitting a bug report (or possibly a feature request as I've seen EL suggest in the forums.)

Answer (score 3):

Doing a test on my local machine, I'd declare this to be a bug.

I see that the resized image used for the category image gets created, but when I reference it by the image manipulation name specified in the Upload Pref I just get "`{category_image:manipulation_name}`" rendered out into the source code while removing and just using `{category_image}` works fine.

Oops - just saw my local install is on 2.5.2 yet. I don't see any reference to the issue in the bug tracker or change log however.